# Windows 8 logon screen background

Tags: windows-8, display, lock-screen

I got irritated by the standard Windows 8 logon screen (the same one as lock screen). How do I change the background?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft account or local account? As I have heard you can customize login screen only if you are registered to a Microsoft account.

Comment: yeah, I have the Microsoft account linked with my Win8, so the solution worked for me. Can't tell about unregistered users though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and go to "Change PC Settings" Very first things that shows up will be the options for the "lock screen image".